# PUT/Update Foreign Key & Many To Many relationship with just pk, and NOT the whole object

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I've got a User model that has a foreign key and many to many relationship with another model.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    '''
    Custom User model. Countries is a list of countries associated with the
    user. Home country is a single country object
    '''
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(
        Country, blank=True, related_name='user_countries'
        )
    home = models.ForeignKey(
        Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,
        related_name='home_country',
        )
```

and

```
class Country(models.Model):
    '''
    Describes the countries, as well as territories of the world.
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    top_level_domain = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    alpha2code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    alpha3code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    calling_codes = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    alt_spellings = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    subregion = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    population = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    latlng = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    demonym = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    area = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    gini = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    timezones = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    borders = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    native_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    numeric_code= models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    currencies = models.ManyToManyField(Currency)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    regional_blocs = models.ManyToManyField(RegionalBloc, blank=True)
    cioc = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The country model itself has a few many to many relationships, and so it is a nested object. When updating my user model with a PUT request, I can serialize my country object to just show the pk, and I can send the pk of the updated country/countries from my React axios request, but then when I axios GET my user object, it only displays country/countries.

On the otherhand, I can serialize my country objects as nested objects with all their fields and subfields, and then I get the data I want from an axios GET request, but then when I want to update my user object, I have to pass in a country object to my axios PUT instead of just a pk.

Is it possible serialize my country objects in their full nested beauty, BUT ALSO update/PUT my user model by just passing in the pk alone?

I'm updating my user object with select forms, and so it's easy to have an option with the value=pk, and then I can PUT request with just the value.

```
<option value="6">Andorra</option>
```

This is my custom User Detail serializer at the moment:

```
class UserDetailSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
    '''
    Custom serializer for the /rest-auth/user/ User Details Serializer.
    '''
    countries = CountrySerializer(many=True)
    home = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='pk', queryset=Country.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'username', 'email', 'countries', 'home',)

    '''
    Updates the users object in the database. The username, email, countries(a
    list of country objects) and home (country object), are set by a PUT
    request from the frontend.
    '''
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        country_names = [cdata['name'] for cdata in validated_data['countries']]
        countries = Country.objects.filter(name__in=country_names)
        instance.username = validated_data['username']
        instance.email = validated_data['email']
        instance.countries.set(countries)
        instance.home = validated_data['home']
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

I'm serializing the home field by just the pk currently, which like I mentioned, makes it easy to PUT, but then in React the user object I GET has

```
home: 6
```

instead of

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "currencies": [
        {
            "code": "EUR",
            "name": "European Euro",
            "symbol": "€"
        }
    ],
    "languages": [
        {
            "iso639_1": "ca",
            "name": "Catalan",
            "native_name": "Català"
        }
    ],
    "regional_blocs": [],
    "name": "Andorra",
    "top_level_domain": [
        ".ad"
    ],
    "alpha2code": "AD",
    "alpha3code": "AND",
    "calling_codes": [
        "376"
    ],
    "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
    "alt_spellings": [
        "AD",
        "Principality of Andorra",
        "Principat d'Andorra"
    ],
    "region": "Europe",
    "subregion": "Southern Europe",
    "population": 78014,
    "latlng": [
        42.5,
        1.5
    ],
    "demonym": "Andorran",
    "area": 468.0,
    "gini": null,
    "timezones": [
        "UTC+01:00"
    ],
    "borders": [
        "FRA",
        "ESP"
    ],
    "native_name": "Andorra",
    "numeric_code": "020",
    "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/and.svg",
    "cioc": "AND"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overwrite the to_representation function in my serializer similar to these instructions: [Django Rest Framework receive primary key value in POST and return model object as nested serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189303/django-rest-framework-receive-primary-key-value-in-post-and-return-model-object)